# non crossing partitions or link patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf

Wondering what packages are generally used to draw non-crossing partitions as matchings on either a line or an *n*-gon. I'm not finding any specific packages on ctan nor any `pgf/tikz` examples, but my guess is everyone just uses `tikz`.

Example of desired output:
[image: a crossingless matching of 6 points on a line]

Minimal working example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw 
(0,0) circle (2pt)-- (1,0) circle (2pt) -- (2,0) circle (2pt) -- (3,0) 
circle (2pt) -- (4,0) circle (2pt) -- (5,0) circle (2pt);
\draw[-] (0,0) to[out=90,in=180] (1.5, 2) to [out=0, in=90] (3,0);
\draw[-] (1,0) to[out=90,in=180] (1.5,1) to [out=0,in=90] (2,0);
\draw[-] (4,0) to[out=90,in=180] (4.5,1) to [out=0,in=90] (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below defines a macro `\Matching` that takes two arguments:

- `#1` is the number of dots (well, actually one less as the numbering starts at 0)
- `#2` is a comma separated list of pairs to be matched

For example, `\Matching{6}{0/3, 1/2, 4/5}` produces the diagram:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\Matching[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(-0.5,0) -- ++ (#1+1,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,#1}{
       \draw[circle,fill] (\x,0)circle[radius=1mm]node[below]{$\x$};
    }
    \foreach \x/\y in {#2} {
       \draw(\x,0) to[bend left=45] (\y,0);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

  \Matching{6}{0/3, 1/2, 4/5}

\end{document}
```

In OP the dots are possibly placed at half integer positions. If this is what is wanted it is easy enough to adjust the definition of the macro.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Yes, I really do want the labels 0,1,... to be under the connecting regions "--" and yes this is easy enough to adjust.

Answer (score 3):

It's not essential to use a package at all

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\unitlength{2mm}
\newcounter{zz}
\begin{picture}(30,20)

\put(0,2){\line(1,0){60}}
\multiput(0,2)(10,0){7}{\circle*{1}}
\multiput(0,0)(10,0){7}{\makebox(0,0){\thezz\stepcounter{zz}}}
\put(20,2){\oval(20,5)[t]}
\put(20,2){\oval(30,7)[t]}
\put(50,2){\oval(10,5)[t]}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Though not as pleasing to the eye as tikz output, good to know! I had no idea about a package free picture environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want half circles, you may want to modify @Andrew 's great answer to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\Matching[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(-0.5,0) -- ++ (#1+1,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,#1}{
       \draw[circle,fill] (\x,0)circle[radius=1mm]node[below]{$\x$};
    }
    \foreach \x/\y in {#2} {
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{\y/2-\x/2}
       \draw(\x,0) arc[radius=\Radius, start angle=180, end angle=0];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
```

[image]